# About Tkinter python 2.76 on Linux Mint 17.2

Tags: linux, video, python

I have 2 functions as below:

```
def select_audio():
    os.chdir("/home/norman/songbook")
    top1.lower(root)
    name=tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()
    doit="play " + name
    top1.lift(root)
    os.system(doit)

def select_video():
    os.chdir("/home/norman/Videos")
    top2.lower(root)
    name=tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()
    doit="mpv --fs " + name
    top2.lift(root)
    os.system(doit)
```

They are selected from buttons to allow choosing and playing *audio files* or *video files*.

They work to some extent.

Videos are in a different directory and at the same level as the audio files.
It doesn't matter which I choose first I see the correct directory so I can play say a video, if after it's finished I choose audio it still shows the video directory.

Similarly if I first choose audio it still shows the audio directory if I select videos.

I have no idea why it does this. I am not an experienced programmer as you can probably tell from the code.

Answer (score 1):

Some suggestions:

1. Use a raw string to make sure that Python doesn't try to interpret anything following a \ as an escape sequence:

Change `os.chdir("/home/norman/whatever")` to `os.chdir(r"/home/norman/whatever")`

It won't solve this problem, but it will avoid you future problems.

2. For *tkFileDialog* use the **initialdir** option:

Change  `name=tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()` to

`name=tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(initialdir=r"home/norman/whatever", parent=root)`

Comment: Thanks guys. Since asking about this I have found a similar problem in another forum which suggested the same sort of thing. I ended up with the code below:'code'def select_audio():
    name=tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/home/norman/songbook" )
    if name =="":
        return()
    aname=name[22:-4]
    var1.set("Playing Song " + aname)
    label1.update_idletasks()
    doit="play " + name 
    os.system(doit)
    var1.set("Finished")

'/code'

Comment: Thanks guys. Found similar suggestions on another forum. Got it working now. Would have posted revised def's but the system here is so weird and why does the enter key end my comment instead of being a newline? Cannot see any rational way to post formatted code so  frustrating and why oh why do I only get 5 minutes to do editing?

Comment: If you have an answer, post it *as an answer* — in the "Your Answer" box.